# How to use a wildcard in the filter value with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How can I use a wildcard when I'm filtering an object with AngularJS

```
<input type="text" ng:model="filter.firstName"">
<div ng:repeat="user in users | filter:filter.firstName"></div>
```

I would like to filter : jean*francois  and get : jean-francois and  jean francois. I'm wondering if there is a way to do that with AngularJs without writing my own filter

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Agreed, it's unclear what you're asking, but as a generic answer you can always write your own filter. They are simple, and you could then do any sort of matching you like.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is put the wildcard in ng-model directive like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filter.$"">
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:filter"></div>
```